# Delphi TCanvas.TextOut displays mirrored Text in Form with WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL

Tags: delphi, canvas, localization, internationalization, right-to-left

I want to write Text on a TCanvas in an Hebrew environment. I set the `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` flag:

```
procedure TForm2.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL;
end;
```

When I write a Text on a TCanvas with TextOut, e.g. **Canvas.TextOut(10, 10, 'Hello World');** the text is displayed aligned right (what I want) but written mirrored (what I don´t want).

Do you have any suggestions how to keep the RTL Layout of the Form and display the Text not mirrored? The Hebrew texts are mirrored as well, so thats not what it should be.

I have a Hebrew text "שם" (=name) added as well to the label at the top. That writing is correct. The same text painted on the canvas with TextOut displays the Hebrew word mirrored which is wrong.

afik setting the `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` flag is the correct way to say windows that the dialog should be mirrored, because there are some Delphi-controls which don´t implement the BiDi mode correctly.

[image]

Comment: Could you give us some screen shots. You won't have enough rep to add them to the Q, but if you post links in a comment, one of the mods can edit them in. Also, why are you using `CreateParams` rather than the built in RTL support?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5j9f5ll9vchxey/ScreenShot699.jpg

Comment: The BiDiMode property doesn´t work correctly to display the whole form from right to left.

Comment: I'd like to help but "doesn't work correctly" conveys no real information. Please edit the question to make this part clear. I fear that your `CreateParams` approach is the wrong solution to the underlying problem. Let's first of all get it clear what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I defined a form with the following properties:

```
object Form1: TForm1
 Left = 192
 Top = 114
 Width = 870
 Height = 640
 BiDiMode = bdRightToLeft
 Caption = 'Form1'
 Color = clBtnFace
 Font.Charset = HEBREW_CHARSET
 Font.Color = clWindowText
 Font.Height = -19
 Font.Name = 'FrankRuehl'
 Font.Style = []
 OldCreateOrder = False
 ParentBiDiMode = False
 OnPaint = FormPaint
 PixelsPerInch = 96
 TextHeight = 18
end
```

And wrote the following code

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
 canvas.textout (100, 100, 'שלום עולם');
end;
```

The output was as expected, right to left.[image].

I don't see any need to override CreateParams.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/faw8ingu7nysm8s/OnlyBiDiMode.jpg This is what happens if only set the BiDiMode to bdRightToLeft. But i need the whole layout switched like in this picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnsmlhzqpke93og/Layout.jpg

Comment: @claaser: It's not clear to me what you want. If I add a radiobox to the form displayed above, English text will be displayed correctly but right aligned (that's easy to fix).

Comment: I want the the whole dialog being mirrored. If the button is normally on the bottom right position it should be mirrored in the bottom left position. This is not done by the BiDi mode. If I change the layout to RTL either with the mentioned CreateParams or with the windows API call SetProcessDefaultLayout everything works fine _except_ writing texts on a canvas. This text is written mirrored and not simply aligned mirrored as the text of labels and captions.

Comment: @claaser: Your comment seems diametrically opposed to what you have written in your question, which states that you *don't* want mirrored text.

Comment: you are right, i _don´t_ want mirrored text. that´s what i thought i wrote in the question.